# What to do in full guard when you are able to grab your opponents knee as he stands up?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu

When you are in full guard, the person on top tries to get up and puts one knee out.  You grab the knee, which lets you control his positioning. Where do you go from there?

Comment: Um...what do you want to do? What kind of grab are we talking about? Gi, no-gi, self-defense, MMA? Did he stand up, or are we looking at when he just put a knee up? If he stood up, did he open your guard or are you hanging?

Comment: No gi. 

He is looking to stand up and starts with one leg, but I still have his head and can reach for the leg.  I looked up the flower sweep and that looks like a viable path, it starts off in a similar position.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g77ug2T0Kao @ 46 seconds is basically the position I was in, but he was trying to get up with the leg I grab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control the opposite arm and flower sweep.